# Callback URL for Deep destination in Connected App

Tags: oauth, connected-apps

We have a connected app and using oAuth.

The requested URL is a resource within a connected app...so not the home page.

It is dynamic so, it can request any page within the target app.

How can we configure the call back URL so that it will respect the requested destination URL after authorization given the fact that it can be any page on the connected site and not necessarily what we define the callback url to be?

Is this a limitation or do we need to make the callback URL page detect the actual destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback URL must match the callback URL of the connected app configuration settings. It is for this reason that developers are allowed to use the state parameter (see docs) so that the callback URL can load the appropriate state information, which may be redirecting to a deep URL, calling some JavaScript function, etc.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the callback URL must contain code to read the state and extract the deep URL to redirect the request?

Comment: Correct. However that may be, the state parameter should identify where to deep link to, and the callback URL should know how to direct the user there after establishing any cookies, session data, etc that the app needs to continue.

Comment: So, for example, if the destination (deep) URL is;

http://abc.com/page?a=10  I would do something like

http://abc.com/page?a=10&state=http://abc.com/page?a=10 ?

Comment: The parameter should be URL-encoded, and the state information doesn't need to be a literal URL unless that's what you need. It could just be `state=page%3Fa%3D10` or whatever else is the minimum information your page needs to construct the deep URL.